# Change value in reactive forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a looped table row which contains a form. I want to update the total field based on the price & quantity in reactive forms. Code is

```
<tbody formArrayName="products">
    <tr *ngFor="let phone of productForms.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Code" formControlName="product_code"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" formControlName="product_name"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" formControlName="product_price"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="product_quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control"  formControlName="total" disabled></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-2" (click)="deleteProduct(i)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

How to update the total value at the time of entering the Price & Quantity.
The typescript code is:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  customer_name: '',
  customer_phone: '',
  customer_address: '',
  products: this.fb.array([0])
});
}
get productForms() {
return this.myForm.get('products') as FormArray;
}
addProduct() {
    const product = this.fb.group({
      product_code: [],
      product_name: [],
      product_price: [],
      product_quantity: [],
      total: []
    });

    this.productForms.push(product);
  }
```

Comment: You can bind change event on your price and quantity input and calculate total price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using template variables like this

```
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" formControlName="product_price" #price></td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="product_quantity" #quantity></td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control"  [value]="(price.value || 0) * (quantity.value || 0)" disabled></td>
```

get the total for all products

component

```
getProductsTotalPrice() : number { 
   let total = 0;
   for(let product of  productForms.controls){
     total += (+product.get('price').value || 0) * (+product.get('quantity').value || 0)
   }
    return total;
  }
```

template

```
 <span>{{getProductsTotalPrice}}</span>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get total of every form array entry? i.e. how can i get total of all rows?

Comment: @SurendraSinghChhabra in order to get for all controlers you have to loop throw all cotrollers and calculate the total

Comment: But since i am using formarray, there is no controller name associated? Then how to loop?

Comment: @SurendraSinghChhabra same like this `productForms.controls`

Comment: I can add this solution to my answer , if don't got my point ? @SurendraSinghChhabra

Comment: sure, add this to your answer